Python LXML etree fromstring parsing returns None
I am trying to scrape some prices of Booking.com, the code works for most of the hotels I'm interested in, but there is a few hotels where the html parser just returns None. I am new to scraping, I can't find the difference between the hotels that work and the ones that don't. Below is the code I'm using:
import requests
from lxml import etree

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/121.0.0.0 GLS/100.10.9850.99"
}

hotel_id = "pension-san-juan"
checkin_date = "2024-05-05"
checkout_date = "2024-05-06"

url = (
    f"https://www.booking.com/hotel/es/{hotel_id}"
    ".en-gb.html?aid=304142&label=gen173nr-1FCAsoRkIVcGVuc2lvbi1jYXNhLW5pY29sYXNhSAlYBGg7iAEBmAEJuAEXyAEM2AEB6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuALivo-eBsACAdICJDdlZWMyNmQ5LWQyZmYtNDQ0My1hMDQ4LTc0YjNlZjM1OTk3ZtgCBeACAQ&sid=f56ef62ad1bef0d20b81f311f764fff0&all_sr_blocks=109833603_88508052_0_0_0"
    f";checkin={checkin_date};checkout={checkout_date}"
    ";dest_id=-401497;dest_type=city;dist=0;group_adults=2;group_children=0;hapos=1;highlighted_blocks=109833603_88508052_0_0_0;hpos=1;matching_block_id=109833603_88508052_0_0_0;no_rooms=1;req_adults=2;req_children=0;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;sr_order=popularity;sr_pri_blocks=109833603_88508052_0_0_0__5400;srepoch=1673781112;srpvid=114c4ebbf8650195;type=total;ucfs=1&selected_currency=EUR#hotelTmpl"
)
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

parsed_response = etree.fromstring(response.text, parser=etree.HTMLParser())

print(parsed_response)

Appreciate if anyone can take a closer look.
Thanks

It would help a lot if you could provide the full response text from one of the hotels that don't work.

the response is quite extensive, not sure if its the best way of sharing. But the code should be fully reproducible.
Update, the parsing works with BeautifulSoup html parser

We care not only about whether a problem can be reproduced right now, but also whether it can be reproduced in five years when a completely different person is trying to learn from your question and its answers. As such, relying on the state of a 3rd-party website or other resource that's subject to change is not ideal.

Bu there's a limit on the number of characters I can use to ask a question, how can I share it?
